# how to store form data in table via controller

Tags: magento-1.9, database, controllers, forms

I need to save form data in table . I need to know better way. Is it better to store from controller. i have tried using following code but no success

form

```
<form id="orderapproval-item-form" class="orderapproval-hidden" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('orderapproval/customercart/remarksdecline');?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="message" class="orderapproval-disabled" value="<?php echo $this->__('Enter decline reason'); ?>" id="decline" />
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Decline'); ?>" onclick="namet()" />
```

controller

```
    public function remarksdeclineAction()
    {
       $message =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('message');
       $model =Mage::getModel('orderapproval/sales_flat_quote_item');
       $model->setItemcomment( $message );
       $model->save(); // save data

    }
```

Model/Orderapproval.php

```
<?php
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_OrderApproval extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
        public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('orderapproval/sales_flat_quote_item');
    }
}
```

Model/Resource/Orderapproval.php

```
<?php
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Resource_OrderApproval extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
        public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('orderapproval/sales_flat_quote_item', 'item_id');
    }
}
```

Model/Resource/Orderapproval/Collection.php

```
<?php
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Resource_OrderApproval_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
        protected function _constuct(){
 $this->_init('orderapproval/sales_flat_quote_item'); 
 }
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <ZetaPrints_OrderApproval>
      <version>3</version>
    </ZetaPrints_OrderApproval>
  </modules>

  <global>
    <models>
      <orderapproval>
        <class>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>zetaprints_orderapproval_resource</resourceModel>
      </orderapproval>

      <ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_resource>
         <class>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Resource</class>
         <entities>
             <sales_flat_quote_item>
               <table>sales_flat_quote_item</table>
             </sales_flat_quote_item>
          </entities>
    </ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_resource>

      <sales>
        <rewrite>
          <quote>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Quote</quote>
        </rewrite>
      </sales>
    </models>

    <blocks>
      <orderapproval>
        <class>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Block</class>
      </orderapproval>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
      <orderapproval>
        <class>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Helper</class>
      </orderapproval>
    </helpers>

    <resources>
      <orderapproval_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval</module>
          <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>Core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </orderapproval_setup>

      <orderapproval_write>
        <connection><use>Core_write</use></connection>
      </orderapproval_write>

      <orderapproval_read>
        <connection><use>Core_read</use></connection>
      </orderapproval_read>
    </resources>
```

its my folder name and file name of model folder

**

1. **ZetaPrints/OrderApproval/Model/Orderapproval.php**

**

1. **ZetaPrints/OrderApproval/Model/Resource/Orderapproval.php**
2. **ZetaPrints/OrderApproval/Model/Resource/Orderapproval/Connection.php**

Comment: mr piyush please reply if you know

Comment: i have updated my question please check and reply me

Answer (score 3):

You tried **magento direct sql query** for insert data in **sales_quote_item_order**.

As, magento **is using ORM and MVC**,so you need to **create a model** for **that table** .

Then **using model save the form data.**

So, you need add

- model and
- resource model
- database connection

add ***config.xml***

**Example:**

```
<models>
    <[ModelPrefix]>
        <class>[YourcompanyName]_[moduleName]_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>[ModelPrefix]_resource</resourceModel>
    </[ModelPrefix]>
    <[ModelPrefix]_resource>
        <class>[YourcompanyName]_[moduleName]_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <[ModelPrefix]>
                <table>sales_quote_item_order</table> <!-- table Name -->
            </[ModelPrefix]>
        </entities>
    </[ModelPrefix]_resource>
</models>
<resources>
    <[ModelPrefix]_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>[YourcompanyName]_[moduleName]</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </[ModelPrefix]_setup>
    <[ModelPrefix]_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </[ModelPrefix]_read>
    <[ModelPrefix]_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </[ModelPrefix]_write>
</resources>
```

and also it **related  Model classes**..

- **Model:** `[YourcompanyName]_[moduleName]_Model_[moduleName]`
- **Resource class :** `[YourcompanyName]_[moduleName]_Model_Resource_[moduleName]`
- **Collection class :** `[YourcompanyName]_[moduleName]_Model_Resource_[moduleName]_Collection`

[Checkout how to create model of table](http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/)

**For save data use model and setter function  at your contorller**

```
$model =Mage::getModel('[ModelPrefix]/[ModelPrefix]>');
$model->setItemcomment($message);
$model->save(); // save data
```

### edit:

**You have done  lot of issue  in folder structure and file name**

All files and folder which you will given u name **OrderApproval** it should   be `Orderapproval` . A should lower case.

**compare config.xml with :**

```
<modules>
    <ZetaPrints_Orderapproval>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </ZetaPrints_Orderapproval>
  </modules>
  <global>

    <models>
      <orderapproval>
        <class>ZetaPrints_Orderapproval_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>orderapproval_resource</resourceModel>
      </orderapproval>
      <orderapproval_resource>
        <class>ZetaPrints_Orderapproval_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>        
              <sales_quote_item_order>
                <table>sales_quote_item_order</table>
              </sales_quote_item_order>
        </entities>
      </orderapproval_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <orderapproval_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>ZetaPrints_Orderapproval</module>
          <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </orderapproval_setup>
      <orderapproval_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </orderapproval_write>
      <orderapproval_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </orderapproval_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
```

Comment: where should i write database query

Comment: As you have  MVC  and magento, so you donot need to rewtite sql  qurry using Model you can save data

Comment: okay i have done as per you please let me check

Comment: but what should i write in controller

Comment: i have added in controller ... $model =Mage::getModel('OrderApproval/OrderApproval');
$model->setItemcomment($message);
$model->save(); // save data

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setItemcomment() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\app\code\community\ZetaPrints\OrderApproval\controllers\CustomercartController.php:383

Comment: Mr Amit i am getting above error

Comment: what is your field name at db?

Comment: field name is itemcomment

Comment: i have updated my question can you check please

Comment: Please share config.xml code?

Comment: i have updated in question please check config.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50823/discussion-between-er-sarvesh-v-tiwari-and-amit-bera).

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari, you need to study magento. Your module have lot of issues.Please study magento module structure

Comment: file name and folder name is in lower case

Comment: i should change OrderApproval to orderapproval everywhere

Comment: please help me i think i have only little bit error

Comment: please check my folder name and file name i have updated in my question

Comment: `$model =Mage::getModel('orderapproval/sales_quote_item_order');
$model->setItemcomment($message);
$model->save(); // save data`

Comment: same error on same line

Comment: i did not get solution can you reply me